# Каждая картинка отдельно или спрайт?

Tags: javascript, html, css, изображения, оптимизация-сайтов

**Возьмём самый распространенный вариант - смайлики. Их очень много (~1500) и отображаются все одновременно, как лучше их выводить?**

1. На сервер храниться одна большая картинка (спрайт) где все смайлики расположены друг за другом, у клиента в css расписаны расположение каждого смайлика (`background-image` и `background-position`) и в html документе с помощью class распознаются смайлики.
2. На сервер хранится каждая картинка смайлика отдельно, у клиента в css расписаны путь до каждого смайлика (`background-image`) и в html документе с помощью class распознаются смайлики.
3. На сервер хранятся изображения отдельно, у клиента только в html документе написаны путь до смайликов (`img[src]`).

**И какие картинки лучше использовать `svg` или `png`?**

Возможно вы предложите ещё более правильный вариант, пожалуйста расскажите максимально подробно, почему именно так?

---

**Второй вопрос заключается в генерации этого списка смайликов, как лучше его генерировать?**

1. Сгенерировать заранее и хранить на сервере в виде шаблона/html документа и подгружать его через ajax и вставлять в html страницу, когда это нужно.
2. Хранить html код в JS коде, в виде строки и вставлять когда это нужно.
3. Генерировать html код из заранее составленного массива хранящийся в js коде.
4. Генерировать код из массива хранящейся на сервер и полученного через ajax.

Так же прошу рассказывать максимально подробно.

Под правильным вариантом подразумевается не только правильно по написанию кода, но и по быстроте загрузки смайликов и нагрузки на обе стороны (сервер и клиент).

Comment: Заинлайнить svg в css?

Comment: @Qwertiy вы имеете ввиду что-то типа этого? `background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1850 1635" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">...</svg>');`   Или как?

Comment: Да. Но я вариант предложил скорее как голосование.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Куда проще пожертвовать загрузкой одним спрайтом на `N Mb`, чем открывать 1500 соединений. Спрайт после первой загрузки в кэш и тяжёлое неудобство исчезнет.
В `HTTP2` попроще в этом вопросе, но настроить сервер грамотно нужно для выигрыша скорости.
Выходит для спрайта лучше юзать одну картинку с `background-position` и классами.
Какой формат лучше - вопрос достаточно сложный, сильно зависящий от конкретной ситуации и предпочтений, для спрайтов лично я обычно использую `png` - разумный баланс качества/размера.

---

Генерировать как картинку, которую прописать `background-image`, браузер сам подтянет, `JS` вообще не нужен.

```
Use the grunt-spritesmith, Luke!
```

**P. S.** Инлайнить в `css` - это зарядить револьвер и поднести к ноге: поддержка сложнее, код распухает, кэшировать картинки нельзя (можно файлы стилей, конечно, но их может автоматически генерировать сервер, выгоды мало).
Однажды я попробовал и отказался.

Comment: Инлайнить можно при компиляции автоматически. При svg увеличения размера нет. Да, вынести все смайлы в отдельный css и его кэшировать.

Comment: То есть сразу в html документе должны быть прописаны элементы с нужными классами и всё? И ещё такой вопрос, почему тогда в VK сделаны именно отдельные картинки ,а не спрайт?

Comment: @Qwertiy, я же сказал что выбрать что лучше - нужно смотреть частную ситуацию, так сказать нельзя, преимущества есть у обоих форматов.

Comment: @Mr_Epic, они же там в gif, что позволяет сделать анимацию. Анимированный спрайт - это жесть.

Comment: @Qwertiy там нету анимированных смайлов, gif формат видемо выбран не для анимации, его часто применяют не только для анимации, не так ли?

Comment: @Mr_Epic, да, если спрайтом делать, то описать позицию для классов и всё. Отдельно грузить каждую картинку - это преимущества как анимации, так и быстрой подменой смайлов на новый, например. Но для этого нужен хороший канал, чтобы сервер не падал, у VK это всё есть.

Comment: @Qwertiy на счёт быстрой подмены смайлов, не понял, в чём проблема так же точно поменять класс у элемента?

Comment: @Mr_Epic, в vk смайл может показываться в диалоге - имеет смысл его быстро там показать. А не грузить весь сет смайлов (в который пользователь может и не залезть) ради одного смайла.